Spring Cloud Gateway Fails to Function Correctly in WildFly
I created a gateway using Spring Cloud Gateway, and it works perfectly when running through IntelliJ. However, when I deploy it to WildFly, it stops working.
The service starts up, but when I make a request through WildFly, it returns a 404
build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.25"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.25"
    war
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.3.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.6"
}

group = "br.org.demo"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

val springVersion = "3.0.5"

extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2023.0.3"
configurations.all {
    exclude(group = "org.springframework.boot", module = "spring-boot-starter-logging")
    exclude(group = "ch.qos.logback", module = "logback-classic")
    exclude(group = "ch.qos.logback", module = "logback-core")
    
}
dependencies {
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.36") // Biblioteca SLF4J
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.36") // Implementação simples do SLF4J
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-gateway
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway:4.1.5")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.12.5")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.12.5")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.12.5")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit5")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")
    
}


dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}

kotlin {
    compilerOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs.addAll("-Xjsr305=strict")
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.getByName<Jar>("jar") {
    enabled = false
}

log in wildfly:

log in intellij

The context root is set to "/".
I removed these dependencies for Spring Boot to work in WildFly:
configurations.all {
    exclude(group = "org.springframework.boot", module = "spring-boot-starter-logging")
    exclude(group = "ch.qos.logback", module = "logback-classic")
    exclude(group = "ch.qos.logback", module = "logback-core")
    
}

I have another microservice in WildFly that works perfectly; it's only the Spring Gateway that doesn't work.
standalone.xml
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="${jboss.mail.server.host:localhost}" port="${jboss.mail.server.port:25}"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>

